# AWS Glacier archives auto deletion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

Is it possible to delete old archives from the vault automatically somehow?
For example I want to delete old archives which are older than 160 days.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938868/expiry-date-for-glacier-backups

Answer (score 2):

I can't find anything in the Glacier documentation about automatic deletion or life cycle rules, and nothing in the console suggests it's possible. You could probably use the Glacier API to query Glacier and delete objects, but I don't think it's built in.

Glacier is really made for long term archiving. If you need shorter term storage you should consider S3. S3 has good lifecycle rules, as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html). Using those rules you can have S3 objects move to the Glacier storage class to save money, then delete after a configured amount of time.

This doesn't quite answer your question, but it's an option to consider.